# How to refactor jquery

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have buttons on the page that will activate and deactive settings. the Ids are the same bar their prefix e.g I have '#rl-activate', '#rl-deactivate', '#cl-activate', '#cl-deactivate' Is there a way to refactor this code so i am not doing it for every button on the page.

```
// rl activate
$('#rl-activate').click(function(){
  $('#rl-activate').hide();
  $('#rl-deactivate').show();
  $('#rl').val(50).prop('selected', true);
  $('#rl').prop('disabled', false).trigger('liszt:updated');
  displayCPM();
  newPrice();
  checkSettings();
});

// rl deactivate
$('#rl-deactivate').click(function(){
    $('#rl-deactivate').hide();
    $('#rl-activate').show();
    $('#rl').prop('disabled', true).trigger('liszt:updated');
    $('#rl').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
    displayCPM();
    newPrice();
    checkSettings();
});
```

So for the next one all that changes will be the rl to cl to bm etc

Comment: You don't really want to refactor jquery, do you: you want to refactor some code written with jquery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('[id$="-activate"]').click(function(){
  var prefix = this.id.slice(0,2);
  $(this).hide();
  $('#'+prefix+'-deactivate').show();
  $('#'+prefix).val(50).prop('selected', true);
  $('#'+prefix).prop('disabled', false).trigger('liszt:updated');
  displayCPM();
  newPrice();
  checkSettings();
});

$('[id$="-deactivate"]').click(function(){
    var prefix = this.id.slice(0,2);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#'+prefix+'-activate').show();
    $('#'+prefix).prop('disabled', true).trigger('liszt:updated');
    $('#'+prefix).val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
    displayCPM();
    newPrice();
    checkSettings();
});
```

This uses the ["attribute ends with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

An alternate solution would have been to change the HTML to use classes ("activate", "deactivate") and a data-attribute ("cl", "rl").

Comment: Instead of `$('#'+prefix+'-activate').hide();` we can use `$(this).hide()`;

Comment: @jfriend00 It reduces the code because OP seems to have this for many prefixes ("cl", "rl", etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Following the DRY principle, you can factor some of the code into a common function, use a duplication style that jQuery uses a lot in its own code and leverage jQuery chaining a little more:

```
 function clickCommon(itemToHide, itemToShow) {
    $(itemToHide).hide()
    $(itemToShow).show();
    displayCPM();
    newPrice();
    checkSettings();
 }

 ["#rl", "#cl"].each(function(pref) {

     $(pref + "-activate").click(function() {
         clickCommon(this, pref + "-deactivate");
         $(pref).val(50).prop('selected', true)
            .prop('disabled', false).trigger('liszt:updated');
     });

     $(pref + "-deactivate").click(function() {
         clickCommon(this, pref + "-activate");
         $(pref).prop('disabled', true).trigger('liszt:updated');
             .val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
     });
 });
```

Techniques used:

1. Factor common code between the activate and deactivate clicks into a common function
2. Use `.each()` to iterate prefixes from an array (jQuery does this a lot internally in its implementation)
3. Use `this` when possible rather than refinding the current element
4. Construct the activate and deactivate id values in code for each prefix
5. Use jQuery chaining for all methods called on a common jQuery selector

Comment: I think you didn't understand  OP's problem (*"e.g I have '#rl-activate', '#rl-deactivate', '#cl-activate', '#cl-deactivate'"*).

Comment: @dystroy - changed to a new method that supports an arbitrary number of prefixes.